# How to send IPC message from renderer to webview in renderer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Using Electron's `ipcRenderer`, is it possible to send a message to a `<webview>` element?

I have tried:

```
var webview = document.getElementsByTagName("webview")[0];
webview.send("test", "testing");
```

and

```
ipcRenderer.send("test", "testing");
```

and tried to receive it within the `webview` using:

```
ipcRenderer.on("test", function(e) {
// do something with (e)
})
```

and

```
window.addEventListener("test", function() {
// do something with (e)
})
```

But none of these methods are being received by `webview`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [electron webview documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#webviewsendchannel-arg1-arg2-) what you have there looks like it should basically work.

However at the top of the webview documentation it does have [this warning](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#warning) which may be causing some issues in the version you are currently testing with:

> **Warning**
>
> Electron's webview tag is based on Chromium's webview, which is undergoing dramatic architectural changes. This impacts the stability of webviews, including rendering, navigation, and event routing. We currently recommend to not use the webview tag and to consider alternatives, like iframe, Electron's BrowserView, or an architecture that avoids embedded content altogether.

Comment: Changed my method to a Browser Window, with IPC via main and renderer, and everything is functioning. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

[An example of sending messages from the main process to the renderer process:](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-arg1-arg2-)

```
ipcRenderer.on("test", (event, message) => {
  console.log(message)
})
```

Works for me.